# Find a polygon in a geojson database which contains point (x,y)

Tags: java, mongodb, geojson

I have a geojson database which contains polygon coordinates as arrays. I want to check which polygon (array of coordinates) contains a point with (x,y) coordinates, and then return the data of the polygon. Can anybody tell me how to use a mongodb query or a java method for this? I tried using `$intersect` but it doesn't work.

Here's a link to an image of the database: [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjNLr.png)

Comment: You really should be including sample data and code you have tried when asking questions. But a quick glance at your image (and the reason there is a reputation ban on on posting images is because the text is better) would suggest that your document(s) rally just contain a list of things that are possibly polygons under a "GeometryCollection" object. MongoDB really cannot match anything other than the top level object. So if one contained Polygon happened to "intersect", then the whole "GeometryCollection" is considered a match. You probably want to move these to separate documents instead.

Comment: i can send the database which i have if you can give me a mail or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$geoWithin`. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) is the link to use this. And make sure that in the type field you mention `"Polygon"` or `"MultiPolygon"`. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for answer. but the problem is to find using this database. i tried with several queries . i can send u the database if you can give me an email or something.